# Designing SQL table for queue system

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL database, and I would like to build a membership queue system.
However, I do not know how to design tables, so that each time when user input and register personal data, the SQL will automatically assign a queue number for the record. Any website or reference have tutorial for that ?

Also, I am trying to build it with mobile platform, so is it good to use sqllite and parse it with JSON to the web server or use websql ?

Please help, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

There are two unrelated questions there. But in relation to the first part, you just need a standard auto_increment column:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_key` (`name`)
);
```

This table will automatically assign a new id to each record as a name is inserted.